spring boot camel post end point
I am currently working on a Spring Boot Camel project where I have configured a route. However, when I try to access the route using cURL or Postman, I receive a "404 Not Found" response. I would like assistance in resolving this issue.

    @Configuration
    public class CamelWebConfiguration {
        private static final String CAMEL_URL_MAPPING = "/v1/*";
        private static final String CAMEL_SERVLET_NAME = "CamelServlet";
        private final RoutesConfiguration routesConfiguration;

   @Autowired
   public CamelWebConfiguration(RoutesConfiguration routesConfiguration) {
         this.routesConfiguration = routesConfiguration;
   }

  @Bean
  public ServletRegistrationBean<CamelHttpTransportServlet> servletRegistrationBean() throws Exception {
        ServletRegistrationBean<CamelHttpTransportServlet> registration =
                new ServletRegistrationBean<>(new CamelHttpTransportServlet(), CAMEL_URL_MAPPING);
        registration.setName(CAMEL_SERVLET_NAME);
        System.out.println("2222211111111111 " + registration.getUrlMappings());
        routesConfiguration.configure();
        return registration;
    }
}


    @Component
    public class RoutesConfiguration extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        getContext().setTracing(true); // Enable Camel route tracing
        System.out.println("22222222222");
        onException(Exception.class)
                .handled(true)
                .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, log, "Error processing XML request: ${exception.message}")
                .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, constant(500))
                .setBody(constant("Error processing XML request"))
                .to("direct:errorHandler");

        from("direct:errorHandler")
                .log("Handling error: ${body}")
                // Additional error handling logic goes here
                .end();

        // Configure REST configuration
        restConfiguration()
                .enableCORS(true)
                .port(5001)
                .component("servlet")
                .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto);

        // Define existing REST endpoint
        rest("/test")
                .post("/api")
                .id("api-route")
                .consumes("application/xml; charset=UTF-8")
                .produces("application/xml; charset=UTF-8")
                .routeId("request-handler")
                .type(String.class)
                .outType(String.class)
                .to("direct:processXml");

        // Camel route for processing XML data
        from("direct:processXml")
                .autoStartup(true)
                .routeId("request-handler")
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, log, "Received XML request: ${body}")
                .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST"))
                .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/xml"))
                .setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOut)
                .convertBodyTo(String.class)
                .process(xmlProcessor)
                .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, constant(200))
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Processed XML response: ${body}")
                .end();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void startRoute() throws Exception {
        RouteController routeController = camelContext.getRouteController();
        routeController.startRoute("request-handler");
    }
}

I am currently working on a Spring Boot Camel project where I have configured a route. However, when I try to access the route using cURL or Postman, I receive a "404 Not Found" response. I would like assistance in resolving this issue.
but
when i am trying url with either postman or curl it have a response 404 notfound
camel version 4.3.0 spring boot 3.2.4 java 17
http://localhost:5001/v1/test/api

Check your code snippet
rest("/test/").post("/api") that would construct the endpoint as /test//api
you can try with either
rest("/test").post("/api")
or
rest("/test/").post("api")

okay thank you but still  have 404 not found response

The error is pretty clear, looks like your Camel route is not being properly registered or matched for the URL, I can see you configure CAMEL_URL_MAPPING = "/v1/*";
which again construct the URI as /v1//test/api

i update to  rest("test")
.post("/api")  but still persist 404
